# Is there a program for analyzing NTP server statistics?

Tags: 12.04, ntp

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 and have the NTP server running, apparently OK. I run the Meinberg NTP server on my two Windows 7 boxes and use its associated server monitor to keep track of what it's up to.

Is there a similar Linux monitor, preferably one with a GUI that can show me how my clock is behaving, etc?

Comment: It is not clear what statistics you are after? You seem to be stressing the server aspect of ntp and not the clock discipline. Do you want to see stats of the sort that any server process would display client connections/ access violations? Or do you want to see things about the clock offset/drift? I will warn you I doubt you will find GUI ntp stats in linux.

Comment: There are numerous plugins for munin.

Comment: As I said, I was looking for something to show me how my clock is behaving. Looking around since I entered the question, I haven't found anything like the Meinberg status program for windows. However, I did find a way to create a graph of the clock offset using GNUPLOT on the daily loopstats files, which should be enough. The simple way only does one day's worth of samples, but a little massaging of the data should allow me to plot the data for all the currently existing loopstats files.

Answer (score 4):

Not a precise answer to your question, but I see you mention you now use a gnuplot script that analyses /var/log/ntp/loopstats. I do the same, and below is the one I use myself.

If anyone is doing something better, I'd be curious too.

```
#! /usr/bin/gnuplot
# Remember to check you have these lines in /etc/ntp.conf and that ntpd is actually running:
#    statsdir /var/log/ntpstats/
#    statistics loopstats peerstats clockstats
#    filegen loopstats file loopstats type day enable
#    filegen peerstats file peerstats type day enable
#    filegen clockstats file clockstats type day enable

# Resolution: fullscreen
set term x11 size `xrandr | awk '/\*/{sub(/x/,",");print $1; exit}'`
set grid
set bars 0.4
set y2tics
set y2range [0:]
set ytics nomirror
set xdata time
set timefmt "%s"
set format x "%T"
set title "NTP statistics"
set ylabel "Clock offset / Roundtrip delay (ms)"
set y2label "Frequency offset (seconds per day)"
set xlabel "Time of day"
local_time = `date +%s --utc -d "12:00:00 $(date +%z)"`
utc_time   = `date +%s --utc -d "12:00:00"`
localdifferencefromUTC = utc_time - local_time
timeoffsettoday = `date +%s --utc -d "today 0:00"` + localdifferencefromUTC
plot \
  "/var/log/ntpstats/loopstats" u ($2+timeoffsettoday):($3*1000):($5*1000/2) t "Clock offset" w errorlines lt 1 lw 2 pt 187, \
  "/var/log/ntpstats/peerstats" u ($2+timeoffsettoday):($6*1000):($8*1000/2) t "Roundtrip delay" w errorbars lt 26 pt 26,\
  "/var/log/ntpstats/loopstats" u ($2+timeoffsettoday):($4*0.0864):($6*0.0864/2) axes x1y2 t "Frequency offset" w errorline lt 7 pt 65,\
  0 w l lt -1
pause mouse close
```

Answer (score 1):

ntp.org offers many [links](http://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Support/MonitoringAndControllingNTP#scripts_stats_tools) to monitoring tools on its website